# Office Live, SkyDrive, pictures and files management

Tags: file-sharing, office-365

I'm using the Microsoft Office Live file space (aka [SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com)) to share my photos.
I have two problems:

1. It seems that I can't get any rational urls for my images. They are something like:

   http://public.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pKdlWYEUvrK-Yoz4rpvaQI_SWnrqIt8GLQk9MDg4E11ZHVF9IPXuKwmr8iZLwcFJtIqiat64iO7kPR42UiY4yG...
   and the urls are changing over time!
2. I can't find an easy way to move multiple files with browser to some other folder.
3. When I use it as a network drive, the root folder is empty.

Others than that, I like the service a lot.

Comment: Thats 3 problems:)

Comment: So either ask a question or delete this product review. :?

Comment: @Michael, I think it's fairly obvious that he wants to know how to solve the 3 issues he's said. use your common sense!
@Tuomas As far as I know skydrive is not designed to be used as a network drive, so be thankful it works at all :)

Comment: I think it would be better to ask each one separately, so you can mark the correct answer to each one as accepted.

Comment: They use to have a UI that shows the URL to access your public files. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this is a known current limitation that is being addressed.
2. Same here.
3. (I wonder how you are adding SkyDrive as a networking drive. This is not currently a scenario Microsoft supports officially. :-)) This is currently by design - SkyDrive does not allow uploading files to the root; only folders are allowed in the root "folder".

Comment: 1 & 2: Good to know. :) 3. How is not supported? You don't need any non-Microsoft-tools to make it: 
http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/totw/skydrive.asp or 
http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7-map-network-drive-live-skydrive-using-office-2010/

Comment: @Tuomas Hietanen - There is no officialy supported by Microsoft way to add SkyDrive as a networking drive. The two tools (Gladinet and SDExplorer) are non-Microsoft and are using a private API that has not been publicly released yet, thus could change at any point (very unlikely, but it could). And the Office 2010 "solution" is an unsupported hack as well, as it is relying on an undocumented temporary (session-specific) HTTP endpoint, which might become a one-time-use enpoint in future.

Comment: It's not undocumented. It's called Webdav.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to integrate Skydrive with MS Office. FREE to download, use or distribute!

Office Live Files - is an Add In for Microsoft® Office that will make your online file management to be simpler. Install our Add In and have access directly from any version from Microsoft® Word, Microsoft® Excel® or Microsoft® PowerPoint® to Office Live files repository.

http://madeforit.com/our-projects/office-live-files